# Replace empty column with contents of another column, with filtering, in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a problem I cannot find the solution to: I am trying to fill the contents of an empty column ( column B)  with another containing content (column A), and I would like to filter the contents of column A before they are placed in column B.

to illustrate:

```
col A                col B  
Br_dis_sp_142321    Br_dis_sp
De_fadop_gy_112341  De_fadop_gp
Fv_ner_rq_142321    Fv_ner_sp
```

I have tried the SUBSTITUTE and REPLACE functions in Excel as well as the find/replace button, and cannot find any straightforward regex functionality but I'm new to Excel and cannot figure this out.

Am using Office Professional Plus 2013

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Would you consider using a macro (VBA)?**

Comment: Hi, yes I am proficient in coding but have never tried VBA, I'd give it a go certainly.

Comment: By "filter", do you just mean stripping out that last bit [letter]_123456?

Comment: Yes that sounds correct, but the characters before vary in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach:

- manually apply an AutoFilter to column **A**
- run the macro
- manually remove the filter

Column **B** will contain the contents of column **A** that were visible at the time the macro was run.  The Macro:

```
Sub CaptureFilter()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, j As Long, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 1
    For j = 2 To N
        Set r = Cells(j, 1)
        v = r.Value
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = v
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is strip out the last 8 characters and append a 'p' to the end, this should work:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-8)&"p"
```

If that's not exactly what you want, explain in words or pseudo code the mapping you had in mind I could provide a richer solution.

```
Br_dis_sp_142321    Br_dis_sp
De_fadop_gy_112341  De_fadop_gp
Fv_ner_rq_142321    Fv_ner_rp
```